# Cannot upload app to Apple Testflight - Need to be Admin

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I want to upload an iOS app to Testflight for internal testing within my team. When I archive and try to upload to App Store (which as I understand is the process for this), I get an error saying that my role is Member, but at least Admin is required. Here's a screenshot;

[image: apple-need-admin-but-has-member]

Now, I checked account roles in various Apple pages and found the following;

- I am an Admin in the App Store Connect team of the company.
- I am only a member in the company's team as per the info on my Apple Developer account membership details.

I am new to iOS development. I am guessing my developer account needs to be admin in the company team in order to submit app to Testflight. Is that correct or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

it may not be enough just to be assigned a role via iTC - the Admin should also go to the Member Center and send you a ’team' invite.

Using a current Admin or Agent account log-in and go here:  https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people

Select the member account (yours), then press the "Change to Admin" button.

Comment: That page now just takes you to App Store Connect.